# Jquery Mobile Named Anchor in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hi all I am using the following code to add anchor links to a jquery mobile website.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.anchor-link').click(function(e) {
        // Extract the hash in the target. 
        // No hash means that the target is not an <a> tag but one of its children (i.e. an <h3>)
        hash =  $(e.target).get(0).hash;
        if (!hash) {
            hash = $(e.target).parents('a').get(0).hash;
        }
        // Find the page it is contained into (or it is itself)
        page = $(hash).closest('div[data-role="page"]').get(0);

        // Look if we are already in that page
        if ($(page).get(0) != $.mobile.activePage.get(0)) {
            // Change to it and scroll to the anchor
            $.mobile.changePage($(page));
            $(page).on('pageshow', function(){
                $.mobile.silentScroll($(hash).offset().top);
            });
        } else {
            // Just scroll to the anchor
            $.mobile.silentScroll($(hash).offset().top);
        } 
    });
});

</script>
```

This works great if I have a link as below embedded in the  tag and link to the class anchor-link.

```
<a href="#my-anchor" class="anchor-link">My link</a>
```

then in the page

```
<div id="my-anchor">My content</div>
```

but the named anchors on my page are sent as the results of a form so like below

```
<form action="mypage.html#my-anchor" id="form1" class="anchor-link" method="post" data-ajax="false">
<input type='submit' name='button' value='Submit Button' data-theme='a'  />
</form>
```

Could anyone tell me how to modify the jquery snippet to read the links from the form action section and not the a href as above. I think I can fix my issue then.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to achieve? scroll to a specific element within same page?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible solutions, depending on your needs:

- Respond to the form's 'submit' event, instead of an anchor's click event.

  ```
  $("form").on('submit', function() 
  { 
      // Your code here;
      return false;
  });
  ```
- Bind to "form.anchor-link input" (or something similar)

  ```
  $("form.anchor-link input").on("click", function() 
  {
      var parentForm = $(this).parent();
      if(parentForm.length == 0) 
      {
          parentForm = $(this).parentsUntil("form").parent();
      }
      // ... extract url data from the form element ...
      // Your code here 
  }
  ```

I tested both of these methods and they work on the DOM example you provided.

Make sure to return false if you don't want the form to actually run a submit action. For the second option, you may need to restrict the $() search to input[type='submit'].

-Matt

Comment: thanks for the help neither worked for me if I understand you correctly I needed to wrap my original code inside one of those two snippets. I think the issue is my original jquery code is still looking inside the (a) tag and not the (form) one.